# Heat flow simulation C programming problem

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I have been trying to solve a heat flow simulation where I have to change the temperature based on its sorrounding temperature.

If you are interested reading the problem then here is the screenshot
[image: METHOD]

My input file is =  [Input file](https://textdoc.co/U5LVFM7fHG0tNlZI)
My output file should look like this [Output file](https://textdoc.co/avHFiDsBEj8W6TzX)

So far I am doing pretty well but the last condition is, I have to stop the program if the stabilization criterion value exceeds 0.2.

(Remember that the stabilization criterion is a relative change, not a degree change. Relative
change is defined as:
|to – tn|/to
where to is the old temperature and tn is the new temperature)

I am using a do while loop to check whether the value is exceeding 0.2 or not. But it is not workingf at all. I tried using while loop too but do while makes the most sense to me here.

- heatflow.h

```
#ifndef HEATFLOW_H
#define HEATFLOW_H
#define ROW 8                   /* max rows */
#define COL 6 /* max columns */
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void read_data(char filename[], double *, double *, double *, double *, double *);
void initialize_plate(double A[][COL], double , double );
void print_plate(double A[][COL],double,double);
int compute_plate( double A[][COL] , double B[][COL],double h1, double h2,double stab);
#endif
```

- Main.c

```
#include "heatflow.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
double plateA=0; //HEATER/COOLER  A TEMPERATURE
double plateB=0; //HEATER/COOLER  B TEMPERATURE:
double h1=0; //INITIAL PLATE TEMPERATURE #1:
double h2=0; //INITIAL PLATE TEMPERATURE #2:
double stab = 0; //stabilization criterion
char filename[30];
double A[ROW][COL];
double B[ROW][COL];
printf("Enter a filename = ");
scanf("%s", filename);
read_data(filename, &h1,&h2,&plateA,&plateB,&stab); //This function will read the data from the FILE
initialize_plate( A, plateA , plateB); // This function will initialize the plate
print_plate( A,h1, h2); // This function will print the plate
compute_plate(A, B, h1, h2, stab); // This function will compute the problem.
}
```

heatflow.c

```
#include "heatflow.h"
void read_data(char filename[], double *h1, double *h2, double *plateA, double *plateB, double *SCV)
{
    FILE *obk ;
    obk = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(obk == NULL)
    {
        printf("There is no file like that\n");
    }
    else
        printf("File has found\n");

    fscanf(obk,"%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", &*h1, &*h2, &*plateA, &*plateB, &*SCV);

    printf("HEATER/COOLER  A TEMPERATURE =%lf\n  HEATER/COOLER  B TEMPERATURE= %lf\nINITIAL PLATE TEMPERATURE #1: = %lf\nINITIAL PLATE TEMPERATURE #2:= %lf\n STABILIZE CRITERION: =  %lf\n\n\n\n", *h1, *h2,*plateA, *plateB, *SCV);

}
void initialize_plate(double A[][COL], double plateA, double plateB )

{
printf("Initial plate\n\n\n\n");
int count = 0 ;
for (int i = 0 ; i < ROW; i++)
{
    for( int j = 0 ; j<COL ; j++)
    {
        if(count < 4) //within 4 row, we will first print plateA and then plateB
        {
            if ( j <3)
            {
                A[i][j] = plateA;
            }
            if( (j>=3) && (j< COL))
            {
                A[i][j] = plateB ;
            }
        }
        if (count >=4 && count < ROW)  //After 4 row, we will print plateB and then plateA
        {
            if ( j <3)
            {
                A[i][j] =plateB;
            }
            if( j>=3 && j< COL )
            {
                A[i][j] = plateA ;
            }

        }

    }
    count++ ;
}
}
void print_plate(double A[][COL],double h1,double h2)
{
    printf("%60.2lf\n", h1) ;
    int count = 0 ;
    printf("         |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    for (int i = 0 ; i <ROW ; i++)

    {

        for (int j = 0; j < COL ; j++)
        {
            printf("         |  %5.2lf ", A[i][j]) ;
        }
printf("   |");

        printf("\n");
        if (count==4)
        {
            printf("%0.2lf    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|   %0.2lf\n",  h1,h2);
        }
        else {
            printf("         |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
        }
        count++ ;
    }
    printf("%60.2lf\n", h2) ;
}
int compute_plate( double A[][COL] , double B[][COL],double h1, double h2,double
stab) {

   
    double check = 0; //it will store the stabilization criterion value then compare with stab(0.2)

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
                if (((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]) > 0) {
                    check = ((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]);
                } else if (((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]) < 0) {
                    check = (-1 * ((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]));
                }

                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                    B[i][j] = (h1 + h1 + A[i][j + 1] + A[i + 1][j]) / 4;
                }
                if (i == 0 && (1 <= j && j < 5)) {
                    B[i][j] = (h1 + A[i][j - 1] + A[i][j + 1] + A[i + 1][j]) / 4;
                }
                if (i == 0 && j == 5) {
                    B[i][j] = (h1 + h2 + A[i][j - 1] + A[i + 1][j]) / 4;
                }
                if ((i > 0 && i < 7) && j == 0) {
                    B[i][j] = (h1 + A[i - 1][j] + A[i][j + 1] + A[i + 1][j]) / 4;
                }
                if ((i > 0 && i < 7) && j == 5) {
                    B[i][j] = (h2 + A[i - 1][j] + A[i][j - 1] + A[i + 1][j]) / 4;
                }
                if ((i == 7) && (j == 0)) {
                    B[i][j] = (h1 + h2 + A[i - 1][j] + A[i][j + 1]) / 4;
                }
                if ((i == 7) && (j == 5)) {
                    B[i][j] = (h2 + h2 + A[i - 1][j] + A[i][j - 1]) / 4;
                }
                if ((i == 7) && (j > 0 && j < 5)) {
                    B[i][j] = (h2 + A[i][j - 1] + A[i][j + 1] + A[i - 1][j]) / 4;
                }
                if ((i > 0 && i < 7) && (j > 0 && j < 5)) {
                    B[i][j] = (A[i + 1][j] + A[i - 1][j] + A[i][j + 1] + A[i][j - 1]) / 4;
                }
                printf("%0.2lf\t", B[i][j]);
                A[i][j] = B[i][j]; //this will store B array into A array for the future progression

            } printf("\n");
        }



    } while( check > stab) ;
}
```

c

Comment: Ow! Those are way too many `if`s. You only need four, one for each edge, if you set the new temperature to zero first, then add the contibutions of the north, east, south and west neighbours. The tests should determine whether that neighbour is another cell or the outside temperature. You also must copy the contents of B to A after each cycle, so that the new temperature of the current cycle will be the old one in the next cycle.

Comment: Yes I have done it too. I just used too many if(which still give me great result) but the problem is, I tried to do do while condition for stabilization citerion (because it determines program termination) but it is not working at all

Comment: You must find the maximum value of your `check` values. At the moment, you just check the southeast corner. You should also copy the data in a separate loop. When you do that as you go, your east and south vaues are from the previous cycle (as they should be), but your north and west values will be updated values.

Comment: A few pointers about C code structure:   

1. Don't include functions inside your header files.

2. Avoid using too many if statements,makes the code bloated and difficult to follow through.


Maybe do a refactor to narrow down where your problem is?

Comment: I think I did copy. When I run the do while loop, in the do, I copied by A[i][j] = B[i][j].  Since do while run once without any condition and then keep following the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to help you with your assignment without actually doing it for you.

- Before you start your program, you need to understand the problem thoroughly.
- Make sure that compute_plate function give the same results whether we go
  from top-to-bottom, bottom-to-top, left-to-right, or right-to-left.
  Therefore, copy all elements from B array to A array after you finish calculations for all elements.
- The simulation of traversals continues until no element in the array changes by a significant relative amount. MEANING: Check all elements

  ```
      ...
      element_flag = (check > stab);
      all_flags = all_flags | element_flag;
      ...
  } while (all_flags);
  ```
- You must be able to justify each line in your program. Am I doing it correctly?
  And can I do it better?
- Try to avoid hardcoded numbers as much as possible.
- Use if, else if, else when possible.
  For example, change:

  ```
  if(count < 4) {

  }
  if (count >=4 && count < ROW) {

  }
  ```

  To:

  ```
  if(count < 4) {

  }
  else {

  }
  ```
- Try to simplify your if statements: Currently the if statements are 2-dimensional. Therefore, you have 9 complex cases:

  ```
  if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
      B[i][j] = (h1 + h1 + A[i][j + 1] + A[i + 1][j]) / 4;
  }
  if (i == 0 && (1 <= j && j < 5)) {
      B[i][j] = (h1 + A[i][j - 1] + A[i][j + 1] + A[i + 1][j]) / 4;
  }
  ...
  ```

Change them to 6 simple one-dimensional cases:

```
    if (i == 0) {
        top = h1;
        bottom = A[i + 1][j];
    } else if (i == (ROW - 1)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    if (j == 0) {
        left = ...;
        right = ...;
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    B[i][j] = (top + bottom + right + left) / 4;
```

Keep up the good work and have fun programming :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but it's too large to put it in a comment.
Let's have a look at this excerpt in your code:

```
if (((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]) > 0) {
    check = ((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]);
} else if (((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]) < 0) {
    check = (-1 * ((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]));
}
```

First, let's say:

```
x = A[i][j]
y = B[i][j]
```

So you are checking:

```
(x - y) / x > 0 (which is the same as:)
1 - y/x > 0     (which is the same as:)
1 > y/x         (which is the same as:)
x > y
```

So, instead of:

```
if (((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]) > 0) {
```

... you can write:

```
if (A[i][j] > B[i][j]) {
```

Second, let's say that:

```
u = ((A[i][j] - B[i][j]) / A[i][j]);
```

Then you are saying:

```
if (u > 0) {
  check = u;
} else { // if u <= 0
  check = -u;
```

This can be simplified to:

```
check = abs(u); // I don't know exactly if you need 
                // to include some header file for this.
                // Obviously, when you opt for this, no need for
                // the x,y thing I mentioned first :-)
```

As you see, your code can be simplified, just by using some basic mathematical rules and functions.